# Oracle SQL PreparedStatement setdate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date

I'm pulling my hair off, I can't find good solution for it, I've searched some other topics, but still no ideas. I have problem with PreparedStatement, especially with setting date. I know, that oracle Date needs date in format YYYY/MM/DD and java.sql.date in YYYY-MM-DD but any of these schemes don't work well.

```
 String query = "INSERT INTO STUDENTS VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(studentIndex.getText()));
            statement.setString(2, studentName.getText());
            statement.setString(3, studentLastName.getText());
            statement.setDate(4, Date.valueOf(studentDate.getText()));
            statement.setNString(5, studentSex.getText());
            statement.setString(6, studentCity.getText());
            statement.setString(7, studentMajor.getText());
            statement.setString(8, studentSpeciality.getText());
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
```

after launching and writing some example dates in JTextField e.g. 1999-10-20 or 1999/10/20 I have an exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:143)
at Project$7.actionPerformed(Project.java:166)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
SOLVED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the date format explicitly with the SQL statements using TO_DATE, e.g.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO STUDENTS VALUES (?,?,?,TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD'),?,?,?,?)";
```

Then ensure the date format in the Java variable matches. Change the format in the TO_DATE as required if different.

Comment: Don't use "statement.setDate(4, Date.valueOf(studentDate.getText()));", use "statement.setString(4, studentDate.getText());". We're letting Oracle do the conversion via the TO_DATE so we just pass in the string.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to use `Date.valueOf` to parse the date string, you should use `DateFormat.parse` instead. It allows you to set a pattern to specify exactly what the format of the Date string is so it parses properly. In fact, the `SimpleDateFormat` convenience class is probably all you need. See the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)